# Android CMYK mode

Tags: java, android, graphics, cmyk

I have a Bitmap in CMYK mode, which doesn't show correctly, and at some point not at all, on Android. Googling didn't return many answers, so I have to ask here how do I handle CMYK mode images?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Ok, more info as requested. I have a image that is in the assets, and I construct a Bitmap out of it. Then when I construct the Bitmap I do it like:

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The Image is in CMYK mode.
When I put it on a ImageView - it appears as white box. Not shown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help with such a vague question.  'Handle'?  'doesn't show correctly...not at all'?   What form would you expect an answer to take here?

Comment: Please provide more specifics: What have you tried, have you identified any commonality between the situations that don't work, and when the display is wrong HOW is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

CMYK is a format for PRINTING. All "standard" structures , such as jpeg, bitmaps and so on, are for a SCREEN, and read your structure as if it were RGB. Put the result in PDF or other postscript and you'll see it OK.

Answer (score 0):

I made it! I found a nice tool for correct handling *.jpg files on Android platform with uncommon colorspaces like CMYK, YCCK and so on.
Use https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick, it's free and easy to configure android library.
Here is a snippet for converting CMYK images to RGB colorspace:

```
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/cmyk.jpg");
MagickImage imageCMYK = new MagickImage(info);

Log.d(TAG, "ColorSpace BEFORE => " + imageCMYK.getColorspace());
boolean status = imageCMYK.transformRgbImage(ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace);
Log.d(TAG, "ColorSpace AFTER => " + imageCMYK.getColorspace() + ", success = " + status);

imageCMYK.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/cmyk_new.jpg");
imageCMYK.writeImage(info);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Docs/cmyk_new.jpg");
if (bitmap == null) {
    //if decoding fails, create empty image 
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageCMYK.getWidth(), imageCMYK.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
}    
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used the library from https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick
Below is my code, u dont need to create new file on storage:

```
try {
        ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/cmyk.jpg");
        MagickImage image = new MagickImage(info);

        if(image.getColorspace() == ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace) {
            Log.e("ImageMagick", "ColorSpace BEFORE => " + image.getColorspace());
            boolean status = image.transformRgbImage(ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace);
            Log.e("ImageMagick", "ColorSpace AFTER => " + image.getColorspace() + ", success = " + status);
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(image);
        Log.e("ImageMagick", "bitmap is " + bitmap);
        ivCMYK.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MagickException e) {
        Log.e("MagickException", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Mariovc/GetCMYKImage) is an example code using [android-lib-magick](https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick) to display [an image with CMYK colorspare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI8ZH.jpg) (not supported by Android), which is got from an URL.

https://github.com/Mariovc/GetCMYKImage

There are two methods called "getCMYKImageFromPath" and "getCMYKImageFromURL".