# how to create a CMYK image from a RGB BITMAP in android

Tags: android, image-processing, rgb, cmyk

just like the title of the question, i want to ask how to create a CMYK image when i have a RGB image as a bitmap.
I had reads question that generate the CMYK value from RGB value just like this code

```
public static int[] rgbToCmyk(int red, int green, int blue)
{
    int black = Math.min(Math.min(255 - red, 255 - green), 255 - blue);

    if (black!=255) {
        int cyan    = (255-red-black)/(255-black);
        int magenta = (255-green-black)/(255-black);
        int yellow  = (255-blue-black)/(255-black);
        return new int[] {cyan,magenta,yellow,black};
    } else {
        int cyan = 255 - red;
        int magenta = 255 - green;
        int yellow = 255 - blue;
        return new int[] {cyan,magenta,yellow,black};
    }
}
```

but, after i have the CMYK value i still don't understand where to place the value just like Bitmap.setBitmap() on android.
as i know the setBitmap function use the RGB value, not CMYK value...
there are a way to change the image color type to CMYK in android?
I'm a newbie in android, correct me if I wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is a library call to convert the format.  Try android-lib-magick, described in the Stack Overflow question [Android CMYK mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625110/android-cmyk-mode).

Comment: thanks to show me the library @Hew Wolff, but after i add the lib, i have another question,, how to add a bitmap, not a string location.. can i use Bitmap.toString at the ImageInfo?